# NSPopover steals key window making underlying window flash selections. Any fix?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I have a 10.7 app that uses a small NSPopover to display some text. The user is never meant to interact with it.

When the NSPopover appears, the underlying view loses key status, and the selection changes colour, etc. Is there a way to get this not to happen?

Answer (score 5):

I do this:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSPopoverDidShowNotification 
        object:myPopover queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
          [window becomeKeyWindow]; //Reclaim key from popover
          [window makeFirstResponder:previousFirstResponder];
    }];
```

Comment: Thanks - I noted the previousFirstResponder in the answer. The way that makes sense is that you need this, so you also have to register for NSPopoverWillShowNotification and set previousFirstResponder.

Comment: More: This method does not work perfectly for me - the popover gets the key for a bit, so there is a flash. Also you should call makeKeyWindow and not becomekeyWindow